# Unable to use sudo password in script

Tags: bash, docker, ssh, sshpass

I am trying to write a bash script to login to ssh and then run `docker login` command as sudo.

SSH login works fine , but issue is with sudo login.
Command:

```
sshpass -p password ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oServerAliveInterval=120 myuser@172.2.14.1 -p 2222 "echo password | sudo -S - docker login -u=myuser -p='dockerpa#$%' dockerhub.com/docker-repo"
```

Also tried

```
sshpass -p password ssh -tt -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oServerAliveInterval=120 myuser@172.2.14.1 -p 2222 "echo password | sudo -S - docker login -u=myuser -p='dockerpa#$%' dockerhub.com/docker-repo"
```

Error being:

```
[sudo] password for myser: sudo: docker: command not found
```

If I execute `sudo docker login -u=myuser -p='dockerpa#$%' dockerhub.com/docker-repo` directly on the remote server, it works fine.

What am I missing here ? Thank you.

Comment: Where is the "docker" command installed on the remote system? How is that directory added to your (sudo) command path on the remote system?

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents here but shouldn`t you use ?

```
sshpass -p password ssh -tt -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oServerAliveInterval=120 myuser@172.2.14.1 -p 2222 "echo password | sudo -S docker login -u=myuser -p='dockerpa#$%' dockerhub.com/docker-repo"
```

without the - because:

```
 -S          The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from
                the standard input instead of the terminal device.
```

Later edit:
The issue is from docker login , as you use it will prompt for password, you should use:

```
sshpass -p password ssh -tt -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oServerAliveInterval=120 myuser@172.2.14.1 -p 2222 "echo password | sudo -S echo 'dockerpa#$%' | docker login --username myuser -password-stdin dockerhub.com/docker-repo"
```

You can find an example for the non-interactive docker login in the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/

Comment: Without `-S` it prompts for a password, which is not possible while running a script

Comment: I mean remove only only the the minus from "-S -" . You use only the -S flag. I have removed it in my original answer

Comment: Nope, its prompting for password then

Comment: Tested a little , youtr issue is from docker login , use:  sudo -S echo 'dockerpa#$%' | docker login --username myuser -password-stdin docerhub.com/docker-repo' . The ideea is that -p= or --password in docker login will prompt for password.